# How can I loop JsonModel in sapui5?

Tags: json, for-loop, sapui5

I'm making my first app in sapui5.

I want create a login page with sign up and login. 
In sing up I want save user name and password in a external `JSON`. How I can export the `JSON Data`?

In login I want validate password and username but i don't know how to loop the `JsonModel`. 
I try this but of course didn't work.

```
var acountsJson = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("acountsModel");
for(var i = 0; i < acountsJson.length; i++) {
    var obj = acountsJson[i];

    console.log(acountsJson.id);
}
```

Can `sap.ui.core` has multiple Models?

Answer (score 3):

> Can sap.ui.core has multiple Models?

Yes, UI5-Core can hold multiple data models. In your case the model is named "acountsModel". You can add more models with different names.

Once you access your model, by sap.ui.getCore().getModel("acountsModel").getProperty("/"); you can either loop through an array using native for() or using jQuery:

```html
$.each(acountsJson, function(value, index, array){
  console.log(value.id);
});
```

Personally, I like the jQuery approach much more than the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

To get the JSON, you need to access your JSON Property, e.g. "/" for top node ...

```
var acountsJson = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("acountsModel").getProperty("/");
for(var i = 0; i < acountsJson.length; i++) {
    var obj = acountsJson[i];

    console.log(acountsJson[i].id);
}
```